# Wake on Lan tool for Windows?

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan

Can anyone recommend a good Wake on Lan tool for Windows?

Either a commandline/windows app/script to send the "magic packet" and turn on a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use command line and GUI implentations for WakeOnLan available from [Depicus](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/).

Comment: This worked really well and was easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We use the ["Wake On Lan" tool](http://fi3k1.dyndns.org/oette.info/projekte_sw_wol.htm). It has a nice user interface, works very well and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

[SolarWinds Wake-On-LAN](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/wake_on_lan.aspx) (free registration required).

Answer (score 1):

Online Wake On Lan Tool

[W3DT.net Online Wake On Lan](http://www.w3dt.net/tools/wakeonlan/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [wol tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wake-on-lan/) from Thomas Krennwallner.  It compiles on Unix and Windows under Cygwin.